# How to disable button if there is no input?

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner who has just started using visual basic. I want to make my button disabled if there is no input in a textbox I provided. I've tried using the If statement but I failed since I don't have a complete understanding of using the if statement. Can somebody help me, I am lost right now.

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: *"I don't have a complete understanding of using the if statement"*. Then that's what you should be addressing, which means going out and finding information about the `If` statement. That is a general issue. This site is for specific issues. Your problem is not that you don't know how to disable a `Button` based on a `TextBox`. It's that you don't know how to write an `If` statement. At least, that's what you're telling us. It's hard to know for sure as you haven't shown us what you've done so we can't know what you've done wrong.

Comment: is it Winforms or wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to disable a button. You can use the `ValidateChildren()` method for the container of the controls. In this case, the container is a form.

First make sure your text box has `CausesValidation` property set to `True` in the designer.

Next, in the Form_Load disable `AutoValidate`. This keeps the `Validating` event of the text box from running until `ValidateChildren` method is called in the `Button.Click` event. This is less annoying for the user if there are several text boxes that you want to validate.

Refer to MS docs at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validatechildren?view=netcore-3.1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AutoValidate = AutoValidate.Disable
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If TextBox1.Text.Length = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        TextBox1.Select()
    Else
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Validating
    If TextBox2.Text.Length = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        TextBox2.Select()
    Else
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        MessageBox.Show("Validation succeeded!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Validation failed.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'The code to run if validation succeeds.
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
End Sub
```